# Javascript Inheritance Woes

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to wrap my head around prototypal inheritance. 
I've read the MDN documentation on it, but it didn't leave me much smarter. I have the following code so far...

```
var Vertex = function(id, options){
  this.options = options || {};
  this.id = id;

  this.position = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  this.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  this.acceleration = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

  this.toString = function(){
    return this.id.toString();
  };

  this.edge_count = 0;
  this.edges = {};

  if(!this.options.hasOwnProperty('label')){
    this.options.label = {
      text: '',
      direction: 'x',
      distance: '10'
    };
  };
};
```

... from which I want to "inherit" all the properties added by the constructor. Vertex has a paint method that adds a Mesh as the Vertex's `object`. So I wrote...

```
var CameraVertex = function(id, camera){
    Vertex.call(this);
    this.object = camera;
    this.id = id;
};
CameraVertex.prototype = Object.create(Vertex.prototype);
CameraVertex.prototype.constructor = CameraVertex;
```

... so I'd be able to use CameraVertex as a drop in replacement for Vertex (except the constructor, which simply assigns the camera to the Vertex's object property, which would usually hold a Mesh or a Group.

But for some reason, there seems to be no `source.object` when I create an edge between the CameraVertex and a regular vertex.

The complete example can be found at [Social Cartography](https://social-cartography.herokuapp.com) after clicking signin with google and selecting the vertex with your mouse.

Comment: The `CameraVertex` is supposed to "inherit" all the properties defined by the `Vertex` constructor, so this line is there on purpose. After all, I want to be able to treat the resulting CameraVertex exactly like any other Vertex, complete with an `object` property and a `position`, as well as `velocity` and `acceleration`.

Comment: Prototypal inheritance _by definition_ cannot be used to inherit the properties added in the constructor, because those properties are _instance  properties_, and are not part of the prototype.

Comment: By calling BaseClass.call(this) I achieve just that effect.

Comment: Those are still instance properties, though, this is _not_ prototypal inheritance.    That specifically refers to the inheritance of properties (whether methods or plain variables) that are inherited via an object's prototype parents through the `__proto__` chain.

Comment: To be clear, you do appear to be correctly using prototypal inheritance for the constructor, but with instance properties there's no "inheritance" as such - you're just arrange for the same properties to be explicitly added to each instance by chaining the constructors with your `Vertex.call(this)` line.

Comment: I think we need to see your code where you create an edge to help further.  This code here looks fine as far as I can see, but it's unclear how you're actually using it.

Comment: Specifically, the code gets triggered when you click on the vertex that's presented in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the constructor of the inherited Object you need to pass also all necessary parameters.

```
var CameraVertex = function(id, camera, options){
    Vertex.call(this, id, options);
    this.object = camera;
    this.id = id;
};
```

Even though I'm not familiar with THREE so I don't understand your problem with source.object, so far I can see this problem.

Comment: The `Vertex` is equipped with default parameters, so that shouldn't be an issue, right? The function will call `Vertex(id, options)` with options===undefined, at which point the second line will kick in. But you're right. It's not a three.js specific issue, moreo of Javascript issue.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore From the Vertex object you posted, options is optional but the ID is not.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore This is a long shot, but once I went through this book I wrapped my head quite good with inheritance in JS https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes

Comment: The failure to pass `id` in the chained call to the parent constructor shouldn't matter, because the child constructor explicitly adds that same property.

Comment: @Alnitak true that, but as a rule of thumb you should. Imagine if you have some conditional flow in your constructor and your constructor is being called before the property assignment.

Comment: Yes, of course in general, you _should_, but in this code there's no need, so IMHO this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Alnitak Maybe my answer help other users than spot the same problem or similar problems. There are different ways to skin an apple, I was hopping a more open communication with OP so we can dive deeper together.